# on_guild_join() not working and not throwing any errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-3.9

So, I was using Python 3.9 to make a Discord bot that counts your invites. However, I came across a problem with on_member_join(). Even when a member joins it does not call the function or throw an error. TIA

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("A member {} joined!".format(member))
```

Comment: Have you defined intents?

Comment: @Nurqm I did not, though I got it that I need to define intents from Łukasz Kwieciński's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to enable `intents.members`, here's how:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also remember to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)